# What is the difference between function pointers, function object, and lambda functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know each can be passed to another function. All of them seem to me like alternatives with subtle differences.

1. function pointer: a pointer to a function
2. function object: instance of a class that has overloaded the () operator; capable of acting as a function;
3. lambda function: an anonymous function (newly introduced in C++11) that may be defined on the spot and that exists only during the lifetime of the statement of which it is a part

Because of the subtleties, I wonder which of the 3 choices would be the most appropriate in a given scenario. So, experts out there, kindly shed some light (on some selection criteria?) so that I could decide and use them in different scenarios.

Comment: A lambda function *is* a function object. It just happens to be defined with some special syntax. So you're down to two concepts.

Comment: I think it's better to leave them seperate, since they conceptually offer two different services.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is far too nebulous to answer. You need to provide a "given scenario", because there are many, *many* possible scenarios in which one of these might be appropriate.

Comment: @Wug they are exactly the same. Picking between the two is exclusively a matter of convenience.

Comment: -1 please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Personally, I think this is a very good question.  I think some broad guidelines can be given without having to cover details of all possible scenarios.  But maybe I'm wrong (since I don't intend to answer - rather, I'd like to read a good answer...).

Comment: A function object is more than a function pointer since it allows to be initialized with some internal variables (parameters) that (can) influence the behaviour of the function when invoked. You can think of a function pointer as a function object with no parameters and no state.

Comment: I think that you are asking the question the wrong way around: simply put, you would never use a function object or lambda expression where you have a function that can work as is. Conversely, if a function alone doesn't do the job then obviously you're not going to use a function pointer. The more interesting question then, is to ask whether you should implement functionality as a function or as a functor. Once you have an answer to that, then it should be obvious whether that functionality will be used via a function pointer or function object.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question is a bit broad, but I wouldn't be surprised if some of the C++11 experts could give a great answer covering the impact on (a) the simplicity of syntax, (b) expected time/memory performance issues, (c) known problems of each of three choices.

Answer (score 7):

**function object**: An object `f` that you can call with the `f(x)` syntax. This includes function pointers, class objects having an overloaded `operator()` or conversion function to a function pointer/reference.

The Standard has a straight forward definition of it

> A function object type is an object type (3.9) that can be the type of the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1). A function object is an object of a function object type.

In particular, a *function* or *function reference* is not a function object, even though they are callable entities. Some people confuse the term "function object" and take it to mean exclusively class type objects with an overloaded `operator()`.

**function pointer**: An, err, pointer to a function

**lambda function**: I think you refer to the C++11 lambdas. These are not really functions, but special compiler-generated class type function objects that have an overloaded `operator()`.